# ESXI - autostart - stop delay - where to configure

Tags: vmware-esxi

I have a (stupid) question about autostart in ESXI (currently 6.7). There is a `stop delay` which as I understand kill VM if it wasn't able to properly shutdown during that time. But there are two places for setting `stop delay`. First "general setting" above and second per VM. Can someone explain in to me please?[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy&paste [from the documentation](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/6.7/com.vmware.vsphere.vm_admin.doc/GUID-7A132146-2779-4F4B-B39D-EE4F129DB79C.html):

> You can also configure the startup order and behavior for individual virtual machines.
> Use this option when you need the delay of the virtual machine to be different from the default delay for all machines. The settings that you configure for individual virtual machines override their default settings.

The "general" setting is the ... well ... general setting that is used by default. You can change this on a per VM basis if needed.